# How can I get memory usage rate with GKE Kubernetes metrics?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, grafana

I wanna get memory usage rate(percentage?) of GKE cluster and display on the Grafana dashboard.
I wrote Prometheus query something like this.

```
sum(kubernetes_io:node_memory_used_bytes{cluster_name="my-cluster-name"})/sum(kubernetes_io:node_memory_total_bytes{cluster_name="my-cluster-name"})*100
```

I add all memory used bytes and all total bytes because when I query `kubernetes_io:node_memory_used_bytes{cluster_name="my-cluster-name"}` or `kubernetes_io:node_memory_total_bytes{cluster_name="my-cluster-name"}` [it returned multiple memory usage per each node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVSBF.png).

My question is,

1. Is my query OK? Or should I calculate memory usage per each node?
2. What is differences "evictable" and "non-evictable" memory type?
   I read official document, but I cloudn't understand it's meaning.
   Should I calculate memory usage only 'non-evictable' memories?

> memory_type: Either `evictable` or `non-evictable`. Evictable memory is memory that can be easily reclaimed by the kernel, while non-evictable memory cannot.